# Link URLs in Thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I want to create this get URL with Thymeleaf. where token is a model attribute

```
<form method="get" th:action="@{/validate/{id}/${token}/.html(id=${user.id})}" >
```

but token is not replaced:

```
<form method="get" action="/validate/68/${token}/.html" >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable template is the part of [Thymeleaf Link URLs](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls). You may have as many as you like, just add them to the parameters list, separated by comma. Something like the following ...

```
<form method="get" th:action="@{/validate/{id}/{token}/.html(id=${user.id}, token=${token})}" >
```